# How to group SQL queries by only first few letters of a certain column's values?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

I'm using Oracle sql developer. I have a table called `data`, one of the columns titled `name`. Earlier, I wanted to group items by name and get a total count, so I did this:

```
select count(*), name from data group by name;
```

Now, I want to group all the items whose names have first four letters in common. For example, I want to group all rows with name equal to Chris and all rows with name equal to Christine together. Is there an edit in the query above which will make it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `substr()` function:

```
select substr(name, 1, 4) as name4, count(*)
from data
group by substr(name, 1, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate query which would fetch same results.

```
  SELECT name4, COUNT (*)
    FROM (SELECT SUBSTR (name, 1, 4) AS name4 FROM data)
GROUP BY name4;
```